# how to add New UIViewCOntroller Over UiView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have added `subview` in a `UIViewController` and I want a new `UIViewController` Should be loaded on click of button.

Challenge is I am not able to use button in new `UIViewController`.

Code which I have write:

```
DetailsOfDayViewController *aViewController =[[DetailsOfDayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsOfDayViewController" bundle:nil];
aViewController.dateParsing = dateparsing;
[self addSubview:aViewController.view];
```

Comment: Not clearly understand your question. Why you are not pushing or presenting new view controller to current?

Comment: Agree with @Lion here. Can you infinitely push view controllers? If you want the button shown on the first view controller to show in the newly pushed view controller, you need to add the button as a subview of the new view controller's view. This would result in a possible infinite stack of view controllers (push button -> new controller -> push button -> new controller -> etc). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your issue. This is happening because your view controller is being deallocated when you don't have any strong pointers on it.

```
DetailsOfDayViewController *aViewController =[[DetailsOfDayViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsOfDayViewController" bundle:nil];
aViewController.dateParsing = dateparsing;
[self addChildViewController:aViewController];
[self addSubview:aViewController.view];
```

Another fix will be connecting this view controller to a property:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) DetailsOfDayViewController *aViewController;
```

And change your code like this:

```
self.aViewController = [[DetailsOfDayViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsOfDayViewController" bundle:nil];
self.aViewController.dateParsing = dateparsing;
[self addSubview:self.aViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing another controller you can following options

**1. Add SubView**

```
 newViewControllerObj.view.frame = oldViewControllerObj(self).view.frame
  [oldViewControllerObj(self).view.newViewControllerObj.view];
```

**2. Present**

```
  [oldViewControllerObj(self) presentViewController: newViewControllerObj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**3. Push using Navigation** (For this you already have to set navigation controller as root controller)

```
  [oldViewControllerObj(self).navigationController pushViewController:newViewControllerObj animated:YES];
```